# Corona SDK setting volume of native.newVideo()?

Tags: video, lua, coronasdk, volume

How can I change volume level during `native.newVideo()` playing?

This is not working:

```
local function onKeyEvent( event )
local keyname = event.keyName;
if (keyname=="back" and event.phase == "up") then
    if _G.__isOverlay == true then
        storyboard.hideOverlay("slideDown")
    elseif storyboard.getCurrentSceneName() == "screen3" and (tableState == "info") then
        goBack()
    else
        native.requestExit()
    end
end

if ( keyname == "volumeUp" and event.phase == "down" ) then
    local masterVolume = audio.getVolume()
    --native.showAlert( "volume:", masterVolume, {"Ok"} )
    if ( masterVolume < 1.0 ) then
        masterVolume = masterVolume + 0.1
        audio.setVolume( masterVolume )
    end
    return true
elseif ( keyname == "volumeDown" and event.phase == "down" ) then
    local masterVolume = audio.getVolume()
    --native.showAlert( "volume:", masterVolume, {"Ok"} )
    if ( masterVolume > 0.0 ) then
        masterVolume = masterVolume - 0.1
        audio.setVolume( masterVolume )
    end
    return true
end

return true
end

if system.getInfo( "platformName" ) == "Android" then  
    Runtime:addEventListener( "key", onKeyEvent ) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you use audio.setVolume, it's also possible to pass the specific channel as parameter.
I think native.newVideo() might not use the master volume control and might actually use a specific channel instead.
In your case you can try by using audio.setVolume(masterVolume, 0) that will affect all possible channels (1 to 32).

If it works, you should debug by putting a loop with this code to find the actual channel:

```
for i=1, 32 do
    print('channel '..i..' is '..audio.isChannelActive(i))
end
```

Then if you found the channel, use audio.setVolume(masterVolume, channelNumber) to only process the video channel :)

Cheers !

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have get and set volume for all channels (`{channel=0}`) but this is not working ((